# Variance in Generalized Ridge Regression/Weighted Least Squares

Tags: self-study, regularization, ridge-regression, generalized-least-squares

I'm following this collection of papers regarding ridge regression, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09169.pdf , and I ran into this section on the mentioning of generalizing ridge regression.
[image]

And when they get to finding the moments of $\hat{\beta}$ they express it in the following format.
[image]

I've seen several ways to obtain similar calculations with regards to how to get $var(\hat{\beta})$ in terms of least squares and weighted least squares, however this appears to be a special case for penalized weighted least squares. So my question is the following, using a similar format as this collection of paper, if I let $W=W^{-1}$ as is done in most WLS instances. Wouldn't $var(\hat{\beta})$ be expressed as the following,

$$var(\hat{\beta})=\sigma^2 (X^{T} W^{-1} X+ \Delta)^{-1} X^{T} W^{-1} W^{-1} X (X^{T} W^{-1} X+ \Delta)^{-1} $$

As I'm not 100% sure how  express $W^{-2}$ correctly as I wrote it as $W^{-1} W^{-1}$, or is it true that $W^{-2}=W^{-1} W^{-1}$ when it comes to matrices?

Thank you

Comment: How is what you wrote different than the expression for $\mathrm{Var}[\hat{\beta}(\Delta)]$ above?

Comment: Hi there, I wasn't expecting it to be much different. However the part I'm a bit confused on is that I have never really seen an inverse matrix written in the form of $W^{-2}$ so I was just clarifying if that is similar to writing it as $W^{-1} W^{-1}$. I've edited the question to clarify my confusion.

Comment: It is true that $W^{-1}W^{-1} = W^{-2}$, so you're good.

Comment: Great thank you. Is there anyway you can just post that as an answer so I may give you credit for it.